# Angular - res.json() is not a function

Tags: angular

I am having an issue with my API Service. This service connects to my nodejs backend api.

The error says

```
ERROR TypeError: res.json is not a function
```

I am getting this error after recently updated this service to use the HTTPClient instead of Http. Im getting this reponse because im missing the old http with the new? if thats the case is there an new Response and how do i use it?

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';
import { HttpHeaders, HttpClient, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';

import { JwtService } from './jwt.service';

@Injectable()
export class ApiService {
  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private jwtService: JwtService
  ) {}

  private setHeaders(): HttpHeaders {
    const headersConfig = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json'
    };
    if (this.jwtService.getToken()) {
      headersConfig['Authorization'] = this.jwtService.getToken();
    }
    return new HttpHeaders(headersConfig);
  }

  private formatErrors(error: any) {
     return Observable.throw(error.json());
  }

  get(path: string, httpParams: HttpParams = new HttpParams()): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(`${environment.api_url}${path}`, { headers: this.setHeaders(), params: httpParams })
    .catch(this.formatErrors)
    .map((res: Response) => res.json());
  }

  put(path: string, body: Object = {}): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.put(
      `${environment.api_url}${path}`,
      JSON.stringify(body),
      { headers: this.setHeaders() }
    )
    .catch(this.formatErrors)
    .map((res: Response) => res.json());
  }

  post(path: string, body: Object = {}): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(
      `${environment.api_url}${path}`,
      body,
      { headers: this.setHeaders() }
    )
    .catch(this.formatErrors)
    .map((res: Response) => res.json());
  }

  delete(path): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.delete(
      `${environment.api_url}${path}`,
      { headers: this.setHeaders() }
    )
    .catch(this.formatErrors)
    .map((res: Response) => res.json());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 109, accepted):

`HttpClient.get()` applies `res.json()` automatically and returns `Observable<HttpResponse<string>>`. You no longer need to call this function yourself.

See [Difference between HTTP and HTTPClient in angular 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45129790/difference-between-http-and-httpclient-in-angular-4/45129865#45129865)

Comment: So i can remove this entire line ```.map((res: Response) => res.json()); ``` ?

Comment: how to get the headers then from the response ?

Comment: This seems to go for `'Http.post()` too, which makes sense.

Comment: What if I still want to call it? I mean, I need also the raw response

Answer (score 19):

You can remove the entire line below:

```
 .map((res: Response) => res.json());
```

No need to use the map method at all.

Answer (score 13):

Don't need to use this method:

```
 .map((res: Response) => res.json() );
```

Just use this simple method instead of the previous method. hopefully you'll get your result:

```
.map(res => res );
```

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar problem where we wanted to update from deprecated Http module to HttpClient in Angular 7.
But the application is large and need to change res.json() in a lot of places. 
So I did this to have the new module with back support.

```
return this.http.get(this.BASE_URL + url)
      .toPromise()
      .then(data=>{
        let res = {'results': JSON.stringify(data),
        'json': ()=>{return data;}
      };
       return res; 
      })
      .catch(error => {
        return Promise.reject(error);
      });
```

Adding a dummy "json" named function from the central place so that all other services can still execute successfully before updating them to accommodate a new way of response handling i.e. without "json" function.

Comment: Thank you!  I have this exact issue and this worked for me.