# Angular res.json is not a function

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, typeerror

Why is not a function? I’ve read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46630893/angular-res-json-is-not-a-function) but I cannot make it work for my project, the error is shown in the following code

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
}

getListVideos(listId) {
return this.http.get('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?key=' + this.apiKey + '&playlistId=' + listId +'&part=snippet,id&maxResults=20')
.map((res: Response) => {
  return res.json()['items'];
})
}
```

And following error is thrown:

> ERROR TypeError: res.json is not a function
>      at MapSubscriber.project (yt.ts:18)
>      at MapSubscriber._next (map.js:79)
>      at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:89)
>      at MapSubscriber._next (map.js:85)
>      at MapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:89)
>      at FilterSubscriber._next (filter.js:89)
>      at FilterSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:89)
>      at MergeMapSubscriber.notifyNext (mergeMap.js:145)
>      at InnerSubscriber._next (InnerSubscriber.js:23)
>      at InnerSubscriber.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:89)

Comment: Post all the relevant code (what is this.http?, what are the imports?), and the exact and complete error message.

Comment: output the actual to see if it has `json()` method, you might be using the latest `HttpClient` that doesn't need the `.json()` call anymore.

Comment: @JBNizet I've edited the post

Comment: @BkSantiago if it doesn't need it, how it would be my code? Do you have a page where I can read more about it?

Comment: HttpClient observables don't emit Response objects. They emit the body of the response, already parsed. Read the documentation: https://angular.io/guide/http#making-a-request-for-json-data. Everything is much simpler when you read the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to import Response from

```
import { Response } from '@angular/http';
```

or try to remove it from res to get rid of the error:

```
.map(res => res.json()['items']);
```

Answer (score 1):

I solve it by following the next page:

https://angular.io/guide/http#making-a-request-for-json-data

The `get()` method on `HttpClient` makes accessing this data straightforward. For example:

```
 this.http.get('/api/items').subscribe(data => {
  // Read the result field from the JSON response.
  this.results = data['results'];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

HttpClient automatically imports json. Let’s say you are expecting to read an object of type User.

```
return this.http.get<User>(url).subscribe(user => console.log(user));
The variable user is of type User.
```

Without specifying a type, your response is automatically json. No need to parse it to json.

https://angular.io/guide/http#making-a-request-for-json-data

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue but solved when I removed the CORS extension in my chrome browser