# Angular 5 / Typescript/RxJS - get data from Observable

Tags: angular, observable

I have this typescript method in order to login user:

```
onSubmit() {
    if (this.form.valid) {
      this.authService.login(this.form.value).map(res => this.loginResponse = res.json).subscribe(
        success => {
          console.log('Response: ' + this.loginResponse);
        },
        error => {
          this.loginFailed = true;
          setTimeout(()=>{   
            this.loginFailed  = false;
          }, 3000);
          console.error('ERROR login.component: ' + error);
        }
      );     
    }
    this.formSubmitAttempt = true;            
  }
```

and actually I don't know how to get the response data inhere **.map(res => this.loginResponse = res)**

The output of console.log is:

```
Response: function () {
    if (typeof this._body === 'string') {
        return JSON.parse(/** @type {?} */ (this._body));
    }
    if (this._body instanceof ArrayBuffer) {
        return JSON.parse(this.text());
    }
    return this._body;
}
```

Does anyone have any hint how I get the response object with observables.

Comment: success => {
          console.log('Response: ' + success);
        },

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`response.json` is a function. You need to call them

```
...map( res => this.loginResponse = res.json() )
```

Comment: res.json() is deprecated with the latest HttpClient and no longer available when using angular 5.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46630893/angular-res-json-is-not-a-function?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Yes, json received by default in angular 5

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Angular5 with HttpClient instead of Http then I think you might be able to just remove .map and do this:

```
onSubmit() {
    if (this.form.valid) {
        this.authService.login(this.form.value)
            .subscribe(
                success => {
                    this.loginResponse = success;
                    console.log('Response: ' + success);
                },
                error => {
                    this.loginFailed = true;
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        this.loginFailed = false;
                    }, 3000);
                    console.error('ERROR login.component: ' + error);
                }
            );
    }
    this.formSubmitAttempt = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try that

```
this.authService.login(this.form.value).map(res => res.json()).subscribe(
    resp => {
     this.loginResponse = resp;
      console.log('Response: ' + this.loginResponse);
    },
    error=> //...
```

If using angular 5, you should use HttpClient instead of the deprecated Http class. That way, you won't even need to call

```
.map (res=>res.json())
```

as httpClient automatically converts the response to json format by default