# get json angular 4 from localhost springboot

Tags: json, angular

I have to make a project with angular 4.

I have a web application that return me a json file like this :

```
{
  "Microsoft ": {
     "name1": [
        "link1",
        "link2",
        "link3"
    ],
     "name2": [
        "link1",
        "link2"
    ],
     "name3": [],
     "name4": [],
     "name5": [
        "link1"
    ]
  }
}
```

And I would like to display this file with angular but I have 2 problems,

I don't know how to manipulate json with angular and I don't know why the MicrosoftResult is empty?

This is my component :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {MicrosoftService} from './microsoft.service';
import {MicrosoftResult} from './microsoft-result';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {Photos} from './photos';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-microsoft',
  templateUrl: './microsoft.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./microsoft.component.css']
})
export class MicrosoftComponent {

  constructor(private microsoftService: MicrosoftService) {
  }

  microsoftResult: MicrosoftResult;

  getJson(): void {
    this.microsoftService.getJson()
      .subscribe(
    data => this.microsoftResult = data,
        error => console.log('Error :: ' + error)
      );
  }
}
```

And my service :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import { MicrosoftResult } from './microsoft-result';
import {catchError} from 'rxjs/operators';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {of} from 'rxjs/observable/of';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class MicrosoftService {

  apiUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/test/';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getJson(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http
      .get(this.apiUrl)
      .map((res: any) => res.json());

  }
}
```

And this is the microsoft result interface :

```
export interface MicrosoftResult {
Microsoft: JSON;
}
```

Then this is the html website :

```
<label>Utilisation d'un get : </label>
<button (click)="getJson()">Get</button>
<p>{{microsoftResult.Microsoft}}</p>
```

But the problem is when I open the page on the browser I have an error on the console when i open the website and when i click on the button :

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'Microsoft' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (MicrosoftComponent.html:14)
    at Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as updateRenderer] (core.js:14693)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13807)
    at callViewAction (core.js:14153)
    at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:14085)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13808)
    at callViewAction (core.js:14153)
    at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:14085)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:13808)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.js:15056)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the ?. (safe navigation operator) on the microsoftResult object in the template.

```
<p>{{microsoftResult?.Microsoft}}</p>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response I have less error but it still doesn't work :(

Comment: Try **import { Http } from '@angular/http';** istead of HttpClient

Comment: Okay keep it in. Try removing this line: **.map((res: any) => res.json());**

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to cast to response to a specific object and check the **response.json().data** in your code like in this part of the angular tutorial v4:
 https://v4.angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6

```
private heroesUrl = 'api/heroes';  // URL to web api

constructor(private http: Http) { }

getHeroes(): Promise<Hero[]> {
  return this.http.get(this.heroesUrl)
             .toPromise()
             .then(response => response.json().data as Hero[])
             .catch(this.handleError);
}

private handleError(error: any): Promise<any> {
  console.error('An error occurred', error); // for demo purposes only
  return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
}
```

Comment: Maybe you need to use the { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

Answer (score 0):

There are several improvements need to be done in your code like :-

1) The expected JSON that you have written has `"Microsoft "` not `"Microsoft"` but I think it might be a typo from your side.

2) `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'Microsoft' of undefined`. This error is thrown because when your HTML is rendering, the value of `microsoftResult` is actually undefined because you have not initialized this with default value.

3) In your function, assign the `Microsoft` property if it exists i.e

```
getJson(): void {
    this.microsoftService.getJson().subscribe(
        data => {
            if(data.Microsoft){
                 this.microsoftResult.Microsoft = data.Microsoft;
            } else { 
                 // Something else
            }
        },
        error => console.log('Error :: ' + error)
     );
  }
```

Comment: thank you for your response but i have another error,
`Error :: TypeError: res.json is not a function`

Comment: You don't need to use `.json()` as you are using **HttpClient**. Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46630922/7265553)

Comment: I got the object and it's work but i don't know how to extract the value of "Microsoft" from the json returned by the get and assign it to the Microsoft attribute of the MicrosoftResult ...
sorry for my english :(

Comment: And the microsoftResult stay empty