# Call data to Angular FrontEnd from Node.js BackEnd

Tags: node.js, angular, angular2-services

I've got a node.js back-end code calling a database and I need to display this data on my Angular from-end.

This is my back-end code:

```
var createError = require("http-errors");
var express = require("express");
var path = require("path");
var cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
var logger = require("morgan");

var indexRouter = require("./routes/index");
var usersRouter = require("./routes/users");

//Own Imports
var cosmosDB = require("./utils/azure-cosmos");
var dataLake = require("./utils/azure-datalake");

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "views"));
app.set("view engine", "jade");

app.use(logger("dev"));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));

app.use("/", indexRouter);
app.use("/users", usersRouter);


// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
// set locals, only providing error in development
res.locals.message = err.message;
res.locals.error = req.app.get("env") === "development" ? err : {};

// render the error page
res.status(err.status || 500);
res.render("error");
});

//Our code starts here
function main() {

//Cosmos Functions
//Gets all devices from cosmos
cosmosDB.findAll("devices", function(docs) {
console.log("Docs found: ", docs);
});

//Gets one device by filter
cosmosDB.findOne("5b4b8d63d08bb1fa920b5f40", "devices", function(docs) 
{
console.log("Doc found find one: ", docs);
});

//Datalake Functions
//Gives you the statuses off all the files in datalake
dataLake.findAll(function(docs) {
console.log("All statuses from datalake: ", docs);
});

//Opens a file with the given name
dataLake.open("5ae6d8e3e892cb63994509fa_1538040038280.json", 
function(doc) {
console.log("Doc requested to be opened: ", doc);
});
}

main();

// app.listen(3000)
console.log("App running on port 3000");

module.exports = app;
```

I created a api.service.ts on my front-end but I'm clearly missing something!
This is how it looks like at the moment:

```
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';


@Injectable()
export class ApiService {

devices = [];

constructor(private http: Http) {}

getDevices() {
this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/devices').subscribe(res => {
  this.devices = res.json();
});
}
```

How can I correctly implement this so I can use the data on my front-end project?

Thank you

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: Use `HttpClient ` instead of `Http` as it is deprecated

Comment: No errors so far.

Comment: what is your issue?

Comment: @Jota.Toledo When I go to 'localhost:3000/devices'; I get error code: Not Found 404 NotFoundError: Not Found.

Comment: That means that you express app has no such route defined. Look at the routing definitions of it.

Comment: I still get error 404: Not Found. I mean, How can I call the list of 'devices' from this function:                                                                         
           cosmosDB.findAll("devices", function(docs) {
console.log("Docs found: ", docs);
});

Comment: Shouldnt you define something in express like `app.get('/devices', function(...){});`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to import HttpClient not Http. Try this:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class ApiService {

devices: any;

constructor(private http:HttpClient) {}

getDevices() {
this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/devices')
    .map(res => res)
    .subscribe(result => this.devices = result);
}
```

This should work fine try it.

You can also define your own structure of the response and you are sending and use it so that you won't have to use the map function you will get the response directly in that format. for example:

```
export interface Result {
    x: string;
    y: string[];
    ...
}
```

and use it like

```
getDevices(): Observable<Result>{
   this.http.get<Result>('http://localhost:3000/devices')
    .subscribe(result => this.devices = result);
```

Refer to these stackoverflow questions also which are similar:

[Angular - res.json() is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46630893/angular-res-json-is-not-a-function)

[Angular2 http.get() ,map(), subscribe() and observable pattern - basic understanding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34671715/angular2-http-get-map-subscribe-and-observable-pattern-basic-understan/34672550)

Comment: `HttpClient` comes from `@angular/common/http`

Comment: oh yeah sorry i copied his code and forgot to change it, thanks for the update.

Comment: When I go to 'http://localhost:3000/devices' I get error code: Not Found
404
NotFoundError: Not Found

Comment: don't mention the complete url just the route or path in your case its /devices