# How can I select one object in an JSON array based on the user input in Ionic 3?

Tags: android, html, json, angular, typescript

I am following an tutorial in Ionic 3 about HTTP. I have made a data provider called **data.ts**. This is my method:

**data.ts**

```
 getRemoteData() {
    return this.http.get(this.statusUrl);
  }
```

I am calling this method in **home.ts** like this:

**home.ts**

```
 ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.dataService.getRemoteData().subscribe(data => console.log(data));
  }
```

This is my result in my google dev tool from `console.log(data)`:

```
 [{"status":"P","plate":"test2","code:"MGP150151","message":"fail"}
,{"status":"P","plate":"test3","code":"MGP160298","message":"fail"}
,{"status":"P","plate":"test4","code":"MGP140085","message":"succes"}
,{"status":"O","plate":"test5","code":"MGP150175","message":"succes"}]
```

The data provider is working good. Now my problem is I want to select just one object in this array. For example: the user enters `test3` based on `plate` and the app must return this result:

```
{"status":"P","plate":"test3","code":"MGP160298","message":"fail"}
```

Then I am binding like this:

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let jsondata of data>
      <span>{{jsondata.plate}}</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I have searched over the internet and I found something like this:

https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

I don't know how to use this on my JSON object array.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Kind regards

Source I used:

https://www.joshmorony.com/loading-remote-json-data-with-http-in-ionic-2/

https://angular.io/guide/http

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13964155/get-javascript-object-from-array-of-objects-by-value-of-property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed the URL and passed a query parameter. This is my code now:

```
getResults(plate) {  
    this.dataService.getRemoteData(plate).subscribe(data => this.jsondata = data)
  }
```

This is working fine!

Answer (score 0):

you can use below snippet to find the specific object

```
    selectedItem;

    this.dataService.getRemoteData().map((res: Response) => res.json()).subscribe(
    data => {
               this.data = data.find(item=> item.plate == $plate)
            }
    );
```

Note : $plate dynamic value, so must pass the value for it.

Comment: Hi Sunil thanks for your time. I hardcoded a value to test if it works. This is what I have now: `this.selectedItem = data.find(item => item.plate == "test3")` and I get an error on `data`: ``Property 'find' does not exist on type 'Object'

Comment: so the response is not Array type. Can you print `data` and  check what values you get.

Comment: yes I posted it below this sentence:  This is my result in my google dev tool from console.log(data). It's an array with JSON objects.

Comment: Here is the sample demo which is working on sample data given https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-r4gkd3

Comment: I think I understand you. First I need to convert this call `this.dataService.getRemoteData().subscribe(data => console.log(data));`into an array variable before I can use the find function.

Comment: Right, you should convert it to `Array` before using `find` function.

Comment: Alright I did this: `var arr = this.dataService.getRemoteData().subscribe(data => { [data] })
    var obj = arr.find(item => item.plate == "test2");
    console.log("found ", obj);` but still can't use the `find` function.

Comment: Are you using http or HttpClient ?

Comment: Yes I am using this: `import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';`

Comment: Updated the answer with http

Comment: I have read  about this solution in this post:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46630893/angular-res-json-is-not-a-function I used your solution and still problems with `data.find()`

Answer (score 0):

If your data contains test3 more than once and you need to use `filter`

```
this.dataService.getRemoteData().subscribe(data => { items = data.filter(item => item.plate === 'enter what you need')});
```

If you want a data, use `find`

```
this.dataService.getRemoteData().subscribe(data => { item = data.find(item => item.plate === 'enter what you need')});
```

Comment: Thanks for you time. I have test both solutions and I get an error on `data.find` and `data.filter`. The same error of the solution above. Property 'find' and 'filter'.

Comment: Can you change `getRemoteData() {
    return this.http.get(this.statusUrl);
  }` function to `getRemoteData() {
    return this.http.get(this.statusUrl).map(response as json);
  }`. Then you should try find operation. If you still get same error, make sure your data object array.