# Parse JSON response in Angular 8 with response.json()

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to get the search data from an API in angular 8. I have a problem with method `response.json()` as it creates an error `response.json is not a function`.

```js
search(query: string): Observable<SResult[]> {   
  const queryUrl = `${url}${params}`;
  return this.http.get(queryUrl, {headers})   
    .pipe(
      map((response : any) => {
        return (<any>response.json())
          .map((res) => {
            return new SearchResult(res)
          })
      })      
    ) 
}
```

Comment: Hi, you can reffer to the link for your problem : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46630893/angular-res-json-is-not-a-function

Comment: please edit your question to be clear

Comment: HttpClient automatically parses the response as JSON you do not need to add `response.json()`. Instead just make it a [typed response](https://angular.io/guide/http#requesting-a-typed-response)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using angular [HttpClient](https://angular.io/guide/http) your request is automatically parsed as JSON (unless the [request's response type](https://angular.io/guide/http#requesting-non-json-data) is not set to handle different data type). As @Alexander Statoselsky said in the comment, you can set the type of your response, so TypeScript will now what data structure is returned from the backend.

```js
search(query: string): Observable<SearchResult[]> {   
  const queryUrl = `${url}${params}`;
  return this.http.get<CustomResultInterface[]>(queryUrl, {headers}).pipe(

    // As HttpClient cares only about the structure, you still need to loop 
    // through the returned data and create a classes if you want the method to return
    // a list of SearchResult classes.
    // CustomResultInterface is your custom interface that carries only the structure of the response
    map(results => results.map(result => new SearchResult(result)))
  ); 
}
```

Also, when using queryParameters, you might want to take a look at [HttpParams](https://angular.io/guide/http#url-query-strings) which you'd use as following example

```js
search(query: string): Observable<SearchResult[]> {   
  const params = new HttpParams();
  params.set('query', query);
  return this.http.get<CustomResultInterface[]>(url, { params, headers }).pipe(
    map(results => results.map(result => new SearchResult(result)))
  ); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Dawid Zbiński. Now I have the follow TypeError: results.map is not a function.

Comment: Well, then the results are not an array. Try console logging it.